# Java if - else return error "String cannot be converted to int"

Tags: java, if-statement

I think I might be completely wrecking the Syntax of a method I am trying to create. The method is part of a larger application that gets the user information to make an invoice.

I get the following error for whatever reason:

`java:43: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int`

Any help is deeply appreciated!

Here is the latest version of code I have tried:

```
public static int inputmethod(String question){
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println ("Input " + question + ":");
    int s=in.nextInt();
    String x = "Wrong, value cannot be 0, please try again!";
    if (s==0) 
        return x;
    else 
        return s;
}
```

Comment: `return x;` ; x is a string, you're supposed to return an integer.

Comment: Logically, return an integer and then from the place where you call this method, check the value of int and print the String you want to print. OR vice versa : return all  string by changing return type as well .

Answer (score 1):

You can't return two different types. You must chose one, for example String and update declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Your method must return an "int" but you are returning a string when s==0

Answer (score 0):

Your method's signature is `public static int inputmethod(String question)` which means you can only return an `int`. You're returning a `String` from your method (`return x`) and that's what causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

You want to return x, the string, not s the integer.

If you want some kind of input validation (don't let the user enter zero) you could wrap the reading inside a loop:

```
int s = in.nextInt();
while (s == 0) {
    System.out.println("Wrong, value cannot be 0, please try again!");
    s = in.nextInt();
}
return s;
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has types, not like javascript wich is dynamically typed.  If you look carefully, you'r function decoration return 'int' type; therefore, you absolutely have to return only an 'int' on this function.

You should output a message or throw an exception like that :

```
public static int inputmethod(String question){

    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println ("Input " + question + ":");
    int s=in.nextInt();
    String x = "Wrong, value cannot be 0, please try again!";
    if (s==0) {
        System.out.println(x);
        return 0;
    }
    else return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for their help!

Basic reason was because the method could only return a integer. So a while loop was needed for input valuation (as well as chanign the dynamics of the code). The code I ended up using was Stefans.

Thanks!!!!!